# Generate Attribute Names from Bean class

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, javabeans

I have a class with the following attributes:

```
public class BeanClas {
    String name;
    String user;
    int year;
}
```

Is it possible in Eclipse to automatically generate the following class?

```
public class BeanClassNames{
    public static String NAME= "name"
    public static String USER= "user"
    public static String YEAR= "year"
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible.<br/>
Whats the purpose of `BeanClassNames`?

Comment: This seems like a very specific use case. What's its purpose?

Comment: BeanClassNames is just a example, but i am using it in a GWT form bindig, and Hibernate JPA querys.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  GWT form bindig, and Hibernate JPA querys.

Comment: Ok then the question is how are you going to use them in JPA queries?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  SELECT e FROM BeanClas WHERE e." +BeanClassNames.NAME+ "= 'somthin'. The benefit is, if i change the attribute name i dont need to change the query

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesn't do this directly, but you can write an Eclipse plugin to do that and similar transformations.  There are Model-to-Text projects in Eclipse that can be reused or you can roll your own re-using the JDT plugins.

Either way, unless you have a whole lot of generation like this to do, you're probably better of just making those changes by hand.

Comment: the project is not big, but i am getting this problem with every new project, and its starts to annoying.